# Jquery post occasionally not calling success or error function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My host is currently having server issues, making today the perfect day to test what happens when my ajax calls fail.

So I'm finding that when something does go wrong, neither my success or fail function in the following are being called: ( simplified for simplicity's sake ).  Currently this will fail completely about one in every 10 times.

I'd like to know how to make sure I can catch all errors in ajax, for example when the server simply doesn't respond, as would be the case today.

```
 myvar = jQuery.post(ajax_object.ajax_url, data, function( response ) {
               console.log( 'success!' );
         })
         .fail(function() {
               console.log( 'sad trombone' );
         });
```

Comment: Have you seen in the Chrome/Firebug ->network tab if the request was called?

Comment: @rogelio Havent used the network tab before... My servers currently completely down, as soon as it comes back up I'll test

Comment: can you reproduce the issue locally?

Comment: @rogelio Don't have a local version of the site, tend to do everything live and just block outsiders by ip.  Server back up,network tab shows ajax request not going through, so I guess that's my question answered.  Is there a way to test if ajax has not been sent?

Comment: Don't know why your event handlers aren't working. You could try adding some [ajax handlers](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/) which attach handlers to all ajax requests

Answer (score 0):

You can try these two ways.

```
          $.ajax({
                url: ajax_object.ajax_url,
                type: 'POST',
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                timeout: 30000,
                data : data,
                dataType: 'json', // use this if you want json response
                error: function() {
                    return true;
                },
                success: function(data) {

                 console.log(data);

               }
           });

       OR  $.post(ajax_object.ajax_url, { data:data }, function(response){ 
             console.log(response);
           });
```

first you simply give an echo "hii"; exit; in the page ajax_object.ajax_url  so you can test whether it is properly redirect to that page..